# Necessary and Sufficient Conditions for a CDF

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

This is an attempt to prove Theorem 1.5.3. in Casella and Berger. Note that the only things that have been proven are really basic set-theory with $\mathbb{P}$ (a probability measure) theorems (e.g., addition rule). Recall for a random variable $X$, we define $$F_X(x) = \mathbb{P}(X \leq x)\text{.}$$

> **Theorem**. $F$ is a CDF iff:
>
> 1. $\lim\limits_{x \to -\infty}F(x) = 0$
> 2. $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty}F(x) = 1$
> 3. $F$ is nondecreasing.
> 4. For all $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, $\lim\limits_{x \to x_0^{+}} F(x)= F(x_0)$

$\Longrightarrow$ If $F$ is a CDF of $X$, by definition,
$$F_{X}(x) = \mathbb{P}(X \leq x) = \mathbb{P}\left(\{s_j \in S: X(s_j) \leq x\} \right) $$
where $S$ denotes the overall sample space.

$(3)$ is easy to show. Suppose $x_1 \leq x_2$. Then notice
$$\{s_j \in S: X(s_j) \leq x_1\} \subset \{s_j \in S: X(s_j) \leq x_2\}$$
and therefore by a Theorem,
$$\mathbb{P}\left(\{s_j \in S: X(s_j) \leq x_1\}\right) \leq \mathbb{P}\left(\{s_j \in S: X(s_j) \leq x_2\}\right)$$
giving $F_{X}(x_1) \leq F_{X}(x_2)$, hence $F$ is nondecreasing.

I suppose $(1)$ and $(2)$ aren't consequences of anything more than saying that $\{s_j \in S: X(s_j) \leq -\infty\} = \varnothing$ and $\{s_j \in S: X(s_j) \leq +\infty\} = S$ (unless I'm completely wrong here). But this seems to suggest that $$\lim_{x \to -\infty}\mathbb{P}(\text{blah}(x)) = \mathbb{P}(\lim_{x \to -\infty}\text{blah}(x))$$
where $\text{blah}(x)$ is a set dependent on $x$. At this point of the text, this hasn't been proven (if it's even true).

I'm not sure how to show $(4)$.

$\Longleftarrow$ I don't know how to prove sufficiency. Casella and Berger state that this is "much harder" than necessity, and we have to establish that there is a sample space, a probability measure, and a random variable defined on the sample space such that $F$ is the CDF of this random variable, but this isn't enough detail for me to go on.

Comment: For (4), use $(-\infty,x] = \cap_n (-\infty, x+t_n]$ for any $t_n \downarrow 0$.

Comment: @copper.hat So basically, show that $\lim\limits_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}F(x+\epsilon) = F(x)$ for all $x$? Do you have any thoughts on $(1)$ and $(2)$, and maybe sufficiency?

Comment: (1) $\emptyset = \cap_n (-\infty,n]$ (2) $\mathbb{R}= \cup_n (-\infty,n]$. Sufficiency can be established (if I recall correctly) by using a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ and taking the 'inverse' of $F$.

Comment: You say $(3)$ is easy to show, but your argument demonstrates only the "only if" part and not the "if" part. The "if" part in this case takes more work than that.

Comment: @copper.hat : The symbols $\text{“}\cap\text{''}$ and $\text{“}\cup\text{''}$ are used in things like $A\cap B$ and $A_1\cap \cdots \cap A_n,$ and $\text{“}\bigcap\text{''}$ and $\text{“}\bigcup\text{''}$ in things like $\bigcap_n (-\infty,n]. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Thanks! I'm a minimalist :-).

Answer (score 3):

This is from *Probability: Theory and Examples* by Rick Durrett, Theorem 1.2.1 and Theorem 1.2.2.

**Theorem 1.2.1.** Any distribution function $F$ has the properties that you listed.

*Proof*.

1. (Non-decreasing) If $x\leq y$ then $\{X\leq x\}\subset\{X\leq y\}$, and the monotonicity of Lebesgue measure gives $P(X\leq x)\leq P(X\leq y)$.
2. (Limitations) It is because $\lim_{x\to \infty} \{X\leq x\}=\Omega$, $\lim_{x\to -\infty} \{X\leq x\}$.
3. (Right continuous) It is because $\lim_{y\to x^+} \{X\leq y\}=\{X\leq x\}$.

**Theorem 1.2.2.** If $F$ satisfies the condition that you listed, it is the distribution function of some random variable.

*Proof*. Let $\Omega=(0,1),\mathcal{F}=$ the Borel sets and $P=$ Lebesgue measure. If $\omega\in(0,1)$, let $X(\omega)=\sup\{y:F(y)<\omega\}$.

If we can prove $\{\omega:X(\omega)\leq x\}=\{\omega:\omega\leq F(x)\}$, the desired result follows from since $P(\omega:\omega\leq F(x))=F(x)$.

To check $\{\omega:X(\omega)\leq x\}=\{\omega:\omega\leq F(x)\}$, we observe that if $\omega\leq F(x)$ then $X(\omega)\leq x$, since $x\notin \{y:F(y)<\omega\}$. On the other hand, if $\omega>F(x)$, then since $F$ is right continuous, there is an $\epsilon>0$ so that $F(x+\epsilon)<\omega$ and $X(\omega)\geq x+\epsilon>x$.