# Necessary and sufficient conditions for a strictly positive, continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}_+$ to be a probability density function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Are there any necessary and suffiecient conditions for a given strictly positive continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}_+$ to be a probability density function of some random variable $X$? I know that for cumulative density functions such conditions exist (e.g., [Necessary and Sufficient Conditions for a CDF](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1594105/necessary-and-sufficient-conditions-for-a-cdf) )

Definetly, we should have that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)dx=1,$ but is this enough?

Comment: As stated, it is necessary and sufficient.  But note: not every PDF is continuous.  And, even more, not every probability distribution is absolutely continuous, that is, there are random variables that have no PDF at all.

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f$ be nonnegative measurable function. There exists r.v. $X$ such that $f$ is a PDF of $X$ if and only if $\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)\, dx=1$.

Proof. Consider experiment where we draw a point at random in the area $\Omega=\{(x,y): \,0\leq y \leq f(x), x\in\mathbb R\}$. Let $\mathcal F$ be a collection of Borel subsets of $\Omega$ with $\mathbb P(B)=\lambda(B)$ where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure and $\lambda(\Omega)=\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)\,dx=1$.

For each elementary event $\omega=(x,y)\in\Omega$ define $X(\omega)=x$. Then for any Borel set $A\subset \mathbb R$,
$$
\mathbb P(X\in A) = \mathbb P\left\{(x,y): x\in A, 0\leq y\leq f(x)\right\} = \int_A f(x)dx
$$
since $X\in A$ when a randomly chosen point belongs to the curvlinear region between $x$-axis and the graph of $f$ with the base $A$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! As we know, if $f$ is integrable then it is measurable so can't we remove the word measurable from the statement? i.e., can't we say that a nonnegative function $f$ is a pdf of some random variable iff $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)dx=1$?

Comment: Well, we can remove this word. No difference.